# Is there a way to check post request parameter size at runtime

Tags: java, tomcat, web

I am struggling with the maxPostSize parameter in tomcat server.xml.
I increased it from the default 2 MByte to 6 mg to solve some problem that we had, and after one week the problem appears again and I increased the size to 10 MByte. I am not sure if it is a good idea to use the unlimited size.

I am trying to find a way to check this parameter size in run time, for specific post requests.( to find out the source of the problem). is there any way to check this param size at run time?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html), check if its a Post request, iterate the request parameters and summarize their sizes. But maybe you should try to change your application to not to send so much data in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HttpServletRequest#getHeader](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29) to obtain `content-length` header which value should be size of the request. It's not exactly what you want but it's the easiest thing you could do for debugging purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an optional header. In a streaming post, it's almost sure it's not present.

Comment: I was thinking to use a web sniffer , actually I can see the parameters when i sniff the specific request but Ii is not showing the sizes